# pyautogui not writing text properly

Tags: python

I am trying to automatically open idle and write a piece of code using pyautogui but putting the \n character is showing unusual behavior.....

```
codestring='def Split(mainstring,separator_string):\n\ta=mainstring\n\tb=separator_string\n\tlst1=[]\n\tlst2=[c1 for c1 in range(len(a)) if a[c1]==b]\n\tlst3=[c2 for c2 in range(len(a)) if a[c2]==b]\n\tlst2.insert(0,0)\n\tprint(lst2)\n\tfor i in range(len(lst3)+1):\n\t\tif i%2==1:\n\t\t\tlst2.insert(i+1,lst2[i]+1)\n\tlst2.insert(len(lst2)-1,lst2[len(lst2)-1]-1)\n\tii=-2\n\tjj=-1\n\twhile ii<=len(lst3)-2 and jj<=len(lst3)-2:\n\t\tii+=2\n\t\tjj+=2\n\t\tlst1.append(a[lst2[ii]:lst2[jj]])\n\tlst1.append(a[lst2[len(lst2)-1]:])\n\treturn lst1\nprint(Split("hello world. Byebye world. Shame on you world. OK world. No world. Please world. Yes world.",\' \'))'
import subprocess as sp
import time
import pyautogui as ui

sp.run('cmd /c start /max cmd.exe')
time.sleep(3)
ui.write(r'idle C:\User\USERS\Documents\split.py',interval=0.023)
ui.press('enter')
time.sleep(6)
ui.write('#the split function\n\n',interval=0.1)
ui.write(codestring,interval=0.2)
```

the output is:

```
#the split function

def Split(mainstring,separator_string):
        a=mainstring
            b=separator_string
                lst1=[]
#^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

i am a newbie in `pyautogui` .This is a humble question........
please help me

Comment: i believe `codeline` would be `codestring` declared in the begenning. if not then can you please specify what is `codeline`

Comment: sorry that is my fault...

Comment: i just figured out i could use \b after \t and it worked.... it is not a proper way tho :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `python -m idlelib <script_to_edit>` you will be able to open and edit the script with idle. So, change

```
ui.write(r'idle C:\User\USERS\Documents\split.py',interval=0.023)
```

to

```
ui.write(r'python -m idlelib C:\User\USERS\Documents\split.py',interval=0.023)
```